# In JavaScript what is meant by 'a function expression is always a constant value'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've been following w3schools tutorials for JavaScript ES6, and after showing some example code for arrow functions:

```
const x = (x, y) => x * y;
```

They state the following.

> Using const is safer than using var, because a function expression is always constant value.

I don't fully understand what they mean here. Are they referring to the fact that I can't edit the arrow function after the expression? Even if that's the case, how exactly does that make the use of const 'safer' than using var? Would something bad happen if I were to write:

```
var z = (x, y) => x * y;
z = x => x *= -1;
```

Comment: Nothing bad would happen. But generally `var` is dangerous. So the alternative here is `let`. But the primary points here is that you usually don't want to reassign something else to the function. So you use `const` so you don't accidentally assign something else.

Comment: That sentence just makes no sense. Any expression evaluates to a "constant" value. You might consider reading better tutorials than w3schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declaring z as const will make sure the function is not overridden later.

Using **var** will allow the function z to be overridden, line 2 in below code will update z with the function (x) => x*= -1;

```
var z = (x, y) => x * y; // this code will be forgotten
z = x => x *= -1; // No Error
```

If **const** is used, line 2 will give error as z value cannot be changed

```
const z = (x, y) => x * y; // Final expression - cannot be changed
z = x => x *= -1; // Error
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you won't get any errors by doing this.

```
var z = (x, y) => x * y;
z = x => x *= -1;
```

But, as you know, functions are intended to contain reusable code and a function is declared to be called later.
If you use `var` for function expression, that means it can be changed later and you will lose the function you declared.

You declare a function on line 1, but without using it, you declare another function on line 2 and that means the first line is not necessary at all.

Your code is equivalent to the below code block.

```
function not_used(x, y) {
  return x * y;
}
function used(x) {
  return x * -1;
}
```

So, why declaring a function that you don't use?